# Hibernate composite key with an auto increment field

Tags: mysql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Here one table having one ID that i want auto increment and two more columns that in composite fashion.

```
ID    ST_NAME    EDU_ID
 1       A         E1
 2       As        E1
 3       Af        E1
 4       B         E2
 5       Ba        E2
```

ID will be unique all the table
ST_NAME and EDU_ID Will be composite type
how can i build the table using hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Entity
Table.java

```
public class Table {

    private Long id;
    pirvate Composite composite;

    // setters & getters
}
```

Composite.java

```
public class Composite{

    private String stName;
    pirvate Long eduId;
    // setters & getters
}
```

Table.hbm.xml

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
    <column name="id" />
    <generator class="increment" />
</id>
<composite-id name="composite" class="com.test.Composite">
    <key-property name="stName" type="java.lang.String">
         <column name="ST_NAME" />
    </key-property>
    <key-property name="eduId" type="java.lang.Long">
         <column name="EDU_ID" />
    </key-property>
</composite-id>
```

Comment: Here EDU_ID is a forgin key referance and ST_NAME will be a class property...I tried with u r example but it shows error in xml @Bob.z